# Should the link I use to access my cPanel have an SSL certification?

Tags: web-hosting, https, security-certificate

My web host (Siteground) provided me with a link that was SSL certified in my user area. This link did not work because the standard error. I asked the support guys and they gave me the same link without SSL certification and it works.

So is this a concern if my cPanel login is not SSL certified?

Comment: No this is not a big problem. actually this is the problem in your web browser . so kindly update it

Comment: Most cPanel hosting providers will use a UCC or wild card certificate for all their servers. It could be that they either didn't purchase one, over-extended it (i.e., over the max allowed domains), or more likely that it doesn't match the server's domain. I would check what domain the certificate was issued to, and if it corresponds to a domain owned by the hosting provider, then the error is likely specific to the domain mismatch, but would still be encrypted. Logging into cPanel over an encrypted connection is highly recommended because it's the entry-point for all accounts on that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to your cPanel does not need to be SSL encrypted.

Comment: Care to expand upon this answer? There isn't really enough here to be an informative answer.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. It's a pretty simple question. Tips?